# How to add values to select component and get seleted option in Appery ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, appery.io

I want to list a 3 options in type select component programmatically and get the selected option value in ionic app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps how you can do that:

- drop `Select` component to the page
- click at `Option` sub-component on the dropped component, in **Properties** panel set:

  - `ng-model` to `viewData.gender` and
  - `ng-options` to `gender.id as gender.name for gender in viewData.genderOptions`
- in `init` function for the page set

  `$scope.viewData = {
    gender: 0,
    genderOptions: [
      {id:0, name:'Male'}, 
      {id:1, name:'Female'}],
  };`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Countries</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="onSelect()">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of countries" [value]="item.id">{{ item.value }}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

`countries` is the list you want to bind to ion-select

```
public countries: Array<{ id: number, value: string }> = [
    { id: 1, value: 'AUS' },
    { id: 2, value: 'IND' },
    { id: 3, value: 'UK' },
  ];
```

"selectedCountry" is initial selected value, in this case country with index 1 in array countries

```
public selectedCountry: any;
this.selectedCountry = this.countries[1].id;
```

You can add value dynamically to countries using javascript Array.push

```
this.countries.push({ id: 4, value: 'USA' });
```

You can get changed value using event `(ngModelChange)="onSelect()"` in selectedCountry

```
public onSelect(): void {
  console.log(this.selectedCountry);
}
```